# IdentityServer4 without ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a legacy app which already has implemented its own dbo structure for users, roles etc thus I don't want to use ASP.NET Core Identity.

However, I would like to implement OAuth2 functionality, so I am thinking about creating authentication server using IdentityServer4.

Can you, please, give me a hint how to wire IdentityServer4 with custom user&password dbo tables?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62199110/9522887 answer. You can add your custom login in ValidateAsync() method of the CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator  class